# Send Output from javascript to html DIV in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have an HTML page in Django where I send my input from the form to javascript and which will inturn will send it to the views, get processed and the output will come to javascript. Now I want to display this output back in the same html page in one particular DIV.

My form is

```
<form id="form_id" method="POST" action="/your_Value/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="your_Value">Sentence: </label>
    <input id="your_Value" type="text" name="your_Value">
    <input type="submit" value="Compare">
</form>
<div class="details"></div>
```

My javascript is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".details").hide();
        $("#form_id").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var friendForm = $(this);
            var posting = $.post(friendForm.attr('action'), friendForm.serialize());
            posting.done(function(data) {
                $(".details").show();
            });
            posting.fail(function(data) {
                alert("Fail")
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Where the values from posting.done() should go to 'details' div.

Kindly let me know how to send the values from javascript to HTML DIV and display it.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: can you please let me know what data you want to display in div?

Comment: The data i need to display is a list...I am getting the output as comma seperated. For example Java, MongoDB, Python is my output from view to the script. How can i display it in a table inside DIV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include a pointer for the output.

```
posting.done(function(data) {
  $(".details").show();  
  $(".details").html(data);
});
```

reference: 
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp